# To prevent threat of SQL injection I have blocked the strings "--" and ";" but still I am not sure whether is it safe or not..?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a textbox in my application in which user will enter where clause to search leads. This conditions will be concatenated to my original search query with `AND` logical operator in stored procedure of SQL Server 2008.

Is it possible to write `DELETE` or `DROP` sub query in that conditions?

Comment: The only **real** solution is to **ALWAYS** use **parametrized queries**.

Comment: +1 to counter the downvotes. Even if the described solution turns out to be naive and problematic, the question itself "shows research effort, is useful and clear" enough at least not to deserve a downvote. It is sad that SO has become such a hostile place for newbies :-(

Comment: [This](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection) is always a good read.

Comment: -1 to counter the upvotes.  Even if the question shows research effort, is useful and clear, I don't know how one could research SQL injection without coming across info on parameterized queries. It is sad that SO has become such a hostile place to properly voting on questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are fighting a losing battle.

Do not try to prevent SQL Injection by black-listing or white-listing contents of input. Instead, use parameterized queries. Then it does not matter what is entered.

Comment: Ok..thanks for the reply but can you suggest some examples of parameterized query in SQL Server 2008 and c#..??

Comment: And also in my module of leads there are so many search parameters and the user wants query textbox for searching thats why i wanna make sure of prevention against SQL injection. Please help if possible.

Comment: Parameterized queries are not always a solution, e.g. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(parameter1, parameter2, etc)`. If you know how to use parametrized query in such case, I'd be very happy to read

Comment: ya i have jst read about parametrized queries but as i said earlier it's a requirement  from user so i am asking this question.

Comment: You can quite easily use parameterized queries in your case. That's a completely different question. I was answering your question here: no... that is not sufficient. And, what if someone really wants to search for;  or --?

Comment: OK got it. and i would be so thankful if you can post example for parametrize query in my case.

Comment: That would depend on how you are querying your data. I think you can find questions and answers on doing parameterized queries with ado.net here.

Comment: if user enters data in textbox as shoe below:
FirstName like 'a%'
i replace FirstName with tblLeads.FirstName and than pass it through parameter to Store procedure and concate it to Query.

Comment: @Anshul You have a bigger problem here. You should not allow the direct entry of sql in that manner. Your app is basically allowing sql injection as a matter of operation. You can't use parameters as a direct replacement here; you need to rework your query mechanism from the ground-up.

Comment: Yes i know that and so i asked this question. When user is asking for this only. Still because of my store procedure structure in this particular case it is not having problem.
Thanks for your precious time. And also for future help in this case.